# How to find files in a given directory with ignoring few subdirectories

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext, atom-editor

Lets say I have a directory which contains 10 other sub-directories. But I want to search a particular keyword only in 7 sub directories because i know that keyword does not exist in other 3 sub directories.

So how can I do a folder search for the keyword ignoring these 3 sub directories using either notepad++/sublime/atom editor?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Sublime Text 3 solution.

Let's say you have a folder structure like this opened in Sublime Text:

```
root
    other
    target
        bar
        exclude1
        exclude2
        foo
```

We want to search in *target*, but exclude *exclude1* and *exclude2*.

1. Open the find panel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
2. In the **Where** field, add this filter:

   ```
   target/,-exclude1/,-exclude2/
   ```
3. Search

The filter means "Search in any files that have a folder named *target* in the path, but exclude any files that have *exclude1* or *exclude2* in the path". If you have some folders that have the same name, but in different locations, you can specify more of the path, e.g. `root/target/,-exclude1/,-exclude2/` You need to include the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ you cannot really do this, according to this discussion here:
https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/10653/exclude-directories-from-the-search

However, a possible workaround (if this is compatible with the rest of your workflow) is to make certain directories hidden.  If you do that, then Notepad++ will not retrieve search results from these directories.

You can hide a directory from the windows command line with `attrib +H /d directory-name`.